# how to use a class inside a function other than main()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I can't call a class and use it in this function as i do in main(). what's wrong with the code, i am using visual studio 2015 community and the errors are:-

```
Error   C2653   'CALL': is not a class or namespace     
Error   C3861   'calling': identifier not found
```

Here is the code:

```
void menu()
{

    int i, j, user;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "* *";
    }
    cout << "  WELCOME TO CRAZY MATH  ";
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "* *";
    }
    cout << "\n\nPlease choose an option...\n_______________________________________\n" << endl;
    cout << "press 1 for basic math calculator\npress 2 for TABLES\npress 3 for a random number" << endl;
    cout << "press 4 for matrix calculator\npress 5 for programmer's converter\n\npress 0 to exit\n" << endl;
    //various options provided to the user, more will be added soon...
    cin >> user; //gets input from the user
    CALL objk; // declared class //but cannot use it shows error
    objk.calling(user);
}

// here lies the class call

class CALL
{   
private:
    int user;

public:
    void calling(int user)    
    {
        if (user == 1) // for bas_cal
        {
            bas_math m1;
            m1.calc();
        }
        else if (user == 3) // random numbers
        {
            srand(time(0));
            cout << "__________________________________\n\nthe random number is: " << rand() % 21;
        }
        else if (user == 2) // tables
        {
            tables tab;
            tab.table();
        }
        else if (user == 4) //matrix
        {
            MATRIX mat;
            mat.matrix();
        }
        else if (user == 0) //exit
        {
            EXIT e;
            e.exi();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: An entity must be declared before it can be used. Typically, this is achieved by placing the class definition into a header file, and `#include`ing this header into any source file that wants to use the class.

Comment: Is `CALL` defined before it is used?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik it should be defined. Declaration may be a declaration  of incomplete type, works only in few cases.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: for the use in the question a *declaration* is insufficient! I needs to be *defined*.

Comment: Documentation can help! http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/7211/header-files#t=201612311451158411244

Comment: Declare the class above where it is used or in a [header(.h) file](http://classes.mst.edu/compsci1570/multiplefiles.htm).